# Is the tensor product of two vector spaces the set of all bilinear forms on the Cartesian product of the vector spaces with entries reversed?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, tensor-products

Let $E_1$ and $E_2$ be two finite dimensional vector spaces over $\mathbb{R}$. Then is it true that the tensor product $E_1 \otimes E_2$, is defined as the set of all bilinear maps from $E_2 \times E_1$ to $\mathbb{R}$?

I ask this question since I know that $ V \otimes V^* $ is the space of all bilinear forms on $V^* \times V$, if $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite; the right way to go is not to "swap" the vector spaces $E_1,E_2$, but to take their *dual*. So the tensor product $E_1\otimes E_2$ should correspond to the set of all bilinear maps $\{E_1^*\times E_2^*\xrightarrow{\sim\ }\Bbb R\}$.

In general, if $E_1,\dotsc,E_n$ are finite-dimensional and $F$ is any vector space,
$$E_1\otimes \cdots\otimes E_n \otimes F \simeq \{E_1^*\times \cdots\times E_n^*\xrightarrow{\sim\ } F\},$$
where $\simeq$ may mean equality or (canonical) isomorphism depending on your definitions. Additionally, note that:

- The *bidual* $E^{**}=(E^*)^*$ of a *finite-dimensional* vector space $E$ is canonically isomorphic to $E$ itself (this is violently false for non-finite-dimensional vector spaces);
- If $E$ is any *real* vector space, as is your case, then it is sensible to assume you are considering tensor products over the real field, and in that case we have the canonical isomorphisms $E\otimes \Bbb R \simeq E \simeq \Bbb R\otimes E$;
- The tensor product is always associative, meaning that there are canonical isomorphisms $(E_1\otimes E_2)\otimes E_3\simeq E_1\otimes E_2\otimes E_3 \simeq E_1\otimes (E_2\otimes E_3)$ whatever the dimension of the vector spaces involved. (Basically, we can drop parentheses.)

The combination of all these facts leads to
$$E\otimes E^* \simeq (E\otimes E^*)\otimes  \Bbb R\simeq E\otimes E^*\otimes \Bbb R\simeq \{E^*\times (E^*)^* \xrightarrow{\sim\ }\Bbb R\}\simeq \{E^*\times E \xrightarrow{\sim\ }\Bbb R\},$$
which is the statement you recalled.

Comment: Ah, so we are identifying the double dual with the vector space itself! (possible in finite dimensions). Also, one can drop the field $F$ in the last tensor product entry in $E_1\otimes \cdots\otimes E_n \otimes F \simeq \{E_1^*\times \cdots\times E_n^*\overset{\sim}{\to} F\}$, if it is clear from the context, right? So $E\otimes E^*$ means the same as $E\otimes E^* \otimes F$, right?

Comment: $F$ is a unit object for $\otimes_F$, meaning that, for any $F$-module $V$, $V \otimes_F F \cong F \otimes_F V \cong V$, naturally in $V$

Comment: What giobrach meant is that it holds for any vector space $F$, not just restricted to $F$ being 1-dimensional.

Comment: @Category_Theorist Thank you for the response.

Comment: @ApoorvPotnis I have updated my answer with more details.